# redis FT.SEARCH on tag type fields and special characters value

Tags: redis

On a Redis index, I inserted the following entry:

id:contact:dacd5f23-e493-4db1-b1b9-74a6783b41b5
FirstName:Dan
LastName:White
website:https://dan.white.com

The "website" field is of type "tag," and I want an exact match, but I'm unable to make it work. If I don't escape the ":", I receive a syntax error. When I escape it with "\:", the syntax error disappears, but I don't get any results.

My exact search query is:

```
FT.SEARCH contact "@website:{https\\://dan.white.com}"
```

I don't encounter any problems running the next query, and I receive the appropriate results:

```
FT.SEARCH contact "@FirstName:{Dan}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The strings in TAG queries are run through text filters which strip out punctuation, stop words, and stuff like that. You need to escape *all* sorts of stuff to make it work, including sometimes spaces. Try this:

```bash
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH contact "@website:{https\:\/\/dan\.white\.com}"
```

Of course, if this is a string in code, you'll need to escape the backslashes as well.

Comment: https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/advanced-concepts/escaping/

Comment: Ya. That too. ;)